# Cannot build android cordova project in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to build an Android project and have just upgraded 'Tools for Apache Cordova' - now update 10. (VS2015 is update 2).
Everything works fine with the 'ripple' emulator, but with other emulators and with a real device I'm getting all sorts of build errors. I even tried starting a  new project, no manual code changes, and got the same problem.
One of the errors is  "Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher." but I have checked and this is correctly installed. 
Furthermore if  try to clean or rebuild the project I get the error  "platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat" exited with code 2." - but again, not if building for the Ripple emulator.

A bit of history - I have been trying to use these Cordova tools in VS2015 ever since they appeared : each new release appears to bring new build issues.

Comment: Try overriding the ADT_HOME and JAVA_HOME under tools->options->Tools for Apache Cordova-> Environment Variable Overrides. Then clean Cordova Cache. And run your project.

Comment: Tried that, thanks, but no success. I had already cleared the cache. However I'm now making some progress by trying different Cordova CLI versions. Still some issues with mismatched plugins; I wlll post an answer when I have it sorted.

Comment: So, if I build with Cordova 4.3 (which I had installed before the VS tools update) a new plain project builds and runs fine. But it won't let me add any plugins, always asking me to update Cordova. If I update Cordova to 6.2, the project won't build (as before, load of meaningless errors). So still cannot proceed. It may help to know that when Cordova is upgraded I get loads of errors suggesting that node is out-of-date, but I just upgraded to latest node and still get same errors

Comment: VS-Tac is now using it's own sandboxed npm(2.14.9). So you got the out-of-date error. It can be changed from tools->Tools for Apache Cordova->uncheck "use a sandboxed version of NodeJS". But from the error message, the problem is related to your android build tools. Could you check again if you have android build-tools 19 installed?

Comment: Definitely had the build tools installed - the dependency checker in Options/Tools find nothing missing, and I also checked the SDK manager listing. Anyway I have now reinstalled Windows and can compile correctly (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to re-install Windows (this is, at least, much easier with Win10 than with earlier versions) - I had been wondering about doing it anyway because of horrendous startup times. Then re-installed VS2015 with Cordova tools.
Surprised to find that the VS install didn't install Cordova along with Cordova tools, I had to do that separately with npm - although there were plenty of warnings (asking me to upgrade minimatch - which I did, without effect).

Anyway the same project now builds correctly in all guises. So I conclude that there was something lurking from an old version which was causing the problems